# Android Handler reset

Tags: android, handler, reset

I use the following code and a handler to produce a beep sound after 5 seconds from when my device is totally flat (accelerometer x,y values). Then the sound reproduces every 5 seconds if the device is still flat. The problem is that the code works fine for the first time that I will have the device flat but if it is not flat and try to put it flat again, the handler does not work and the sound produces immediately and follows the "lastBip" statement. I think I must try to **reset** the handler each time the device is **not flat** but I do not know how. What I want is that when my device is flat the sound should work after 5 seconds all the time that my application is running and not only the first time when I opened it. Does someone know what I must change to my code to work properly? Thank you in advance..

```
 handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
   @Override
   public void run() {

    if (x > -0.1 && x < 0.1 && y > -0.1 && y < 0.1 && System.currentTimeMillis() - lastBip > bipRate) {

        AudioManager mgr = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
        float streamVolumeCurrent = mgr.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_RING);
        float streamVolumeMax = mgr.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_RING);
        float volume = streamVolumeCurrent / streamVolumeMax;
        lastBip = System.currentTimeMillis();
        soundPool.play(bipSoundID, volume, volume, 1, 0, 1);

    }

   }

 }, 5000);
```

Comment: x = event.values[0];
y = event.values[1];

The values that the accelerometer gives. When x, y closes to 0 means that the device is flat.

Comment: Do you have any idea how can I reset the handler when the device is not flat?